# How to determine ASP.NET's generated ID's from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

In ASP.NET, when you give a tag an ID it generates a unique HTML id for the element based on the control hierachy, ie.

```
<asp:Panel ID="test" runat="server">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
<!-- Becomes... -->
<div id="plc_lt_zoneContent_PagePlaceholder_PagePlaceholder_lt_test_test">
    ...
</div>
```

Is there some way of determining the generated id in the codebehind file? I need to generate some Javascript that uses the id.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var theID = '<%= test.ClientID %>';
  // theID contains your ID

</script>
```

**Update:** I noticed a comment below that `ClientId` didn't work. It's `ClientID` (case sensitive). Here's the documentation reference to ClientID:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I get the following ASP error when trying this:error CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: while you may have an error with this particular solution.  The spirit of his answer does seem like a decent solution.  You can output the client Id to javascript after the prerender event.

Comment: Well, yes, I got that before even asking the question. The question was how to retrieve the client ID, which apparently doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: @Matthew... I think it's case sensitive: ClientID not ClientId

Comment: Of course it is, stupid me for missing that. Cheers, it's all working now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ClientID` property, but it is only available from the **PreRender** event (or later).

ASP.NET 4 is going to make some changes to this so that you can get "predicatable" identifiers, but even then it's not a panacea.

Answer (score 0):

Or use ClientIDMode="Static" on the asp.net-element