# Linkbutton causing JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a Javascript code that check if the linkbutton is clicked, I would perform some server side action and after the action is done, will trigger some UI animation.

**Javascript:**

```
function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
 if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == 'lbSearch')
 {
     //Ui animation code goes here...
 }
}
```

**Code Behind**

```
    sp.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbSearch);
```

**ASPX declaration** of the LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSearch" runat="server" CssClass="searchButton" OnClick="btnManualSearch_Click">></asp:LinkButton></span>
```

and also, when I mouseover, it shows

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphTopLeft$lbSearch','')
```

But it keeps showing, "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference ", anyone knows what is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you used `console.log(sender)` or a breakpoint to see what is coming back from your request?

Comment: console.log(sender) in IE10 shows [object object], and I am unable to set a breakpoint in ASPX due to it is a generated page

Comment: on a sidenote, all other controls (e.g. imagebutton) are functioning properly, except the linkbutton

Answer (score -1):

These id what you entered ist for the codebehind. ASP.NET 2.0 generates a other id for the html. So it can not be found in your javascript.... 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/2444239/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444239/)

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all, I have no problem getting the ClientID however it is saying the sourceElement is null, in my case.